# Making compiled typescript code globally accessible

Tags: javascript, typescript, window

I've been working on a little project recently, and ran into this issue of actually having my project me accessible in the rest of the page.

Here's the deal:

It's a javascript router. Doing this just for the sake of interest. I've already set up my typescript compiler via grunt and my module loading and concatenation via grunt-requirejs.

Here's the grunt file: https://github.com/Forestdev/jsRoute/blob/master/gruntfile.js

The output, however, doesn't seem to generate any export to window. I have been googling as to how to export my code to window or anywhere really so that other javascript files could access it.

Could this be the problem with wrapper? Do I need to insert a custom wrapper for all of this? What's the general rule of thumb of making your typescript project global?

Edit:

Forgot to list the index file: https://github.com/Forestdev/jsRoute/blob/master/src/index.ts

Ignore the line with the new instance of an object. I want to export this object so that anyone else could create a new instance of it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to handle exposing to the global scope.

Within grunt build requirejs script I added a custom wrapper, which is:

```
wrap: {
  start: '(function(global) {',
  end: 'global.JSRoute = global.JSRoute || require("index").Router; }(window));'
}
```

This seems to fix the issue I had of exporting my script to a global scope. This also correctly loads the script on window load as well, so other scripts have access to it right away.

Hope this makes sense. Hopefully this is the correct way of doing it as well.